# Converting a table of XMLs into XMLs to use with read_xml R

Tags: sql, r, xml

I have a table full of XML values (all in character format) but unable to use read_xml with it. Have tried using as.list and str to help but get the following errors

*Error in UseMethod("read_xml") :
no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"*

The table has a column full of XMLs in the below format simply titled "XML_M":

```
<Root>
<Product>
    <Test_ID value="1" />
    <Effective_Date value="2022-01-01" />
    <Membership value="Yes" />
    <Request>
      <Request_ID value="1" />
      <Request_type value="Simple" />
    </Request>
    <Request>
      <Request_ID value="2" />
      <Request_type value="Complex" />
    </Request>
</Product>
</Root>
```

The objective is to get all  the XML values and convert them into another table but that has the elements as columns. What I'm really asking for is what do I need to do to allow read_xml to read this column of XMLs.

edit: have attached a sample table here: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R8G7.png)

Comment: The XML you gave is not a table. In a table, every record aka row has the same property names aka columns. A request has the property Request_type, but the Membership does not have the property Request_type. That's my the data is stored in a tree stricture and not in a table. You need to do `read_xml(path)` where `path` is the filename and the directory of teh xml file. `path` must not be another R object e.g. a list

Comment: You say *"column of XMLs"*, does that mean that you have a frame where one column is filled with many of these? Otherwise, this question doesn't really add any context to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71130909/3358272) question, I wonder what's not sufficient about the answer provided there.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, yes, I have a frame where one column is filled with these XMLs. The previous question handled one XML on it's own but the issue here is using read_xml with a single column (populated with many XML messages in each row) in a data frame

Comment: @danloo I specifically said "The table has a column full of XMLs". There is no .xml file. It is a dataframe imported from a SQL Server where a single column houses a large quantity of XMLs in the format listed above.

Comment: `newdat <- lapply(yourframe$column_of_xmls, function(Z) { L <- as_list(read_xml(Z)); rest of previous answer here; })`. After that, if all are the same and stable, you might be able to do `do.call(rbind, newdat)` (or `rbindlist(newdat)` or `bind_rows(newdat)`, depending on your R-dialect preference) to get a single combined frame.

Comment: FYI, the question is about how to deal with a column of these, but your sample data does very little to clearly show this. It would help immensely to have seen an actual `data.frame` with some sample data, perhaps posting the output from `dput(myframe["xmlcolumn"])`. If all are the same structure, then it might be inferred what the expected output is, but if there are any differences then you really must be much clearer about variable data formats and your expectations of them. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question was effectively answered with R methods in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71130909/3358272) by @r2evans where you simply have to iterate down a column of a data frame instead of a single XML file, consider an SQL method by *shredding* the data with below XML query that you can call from R. Below assumes XML column is stored as XML type.

**R** *(adjust my_table and my_xml_column)*

```
...

xml_query <- (
    "SELECT
        Test_ID = prod.value('(Test_ID/@value)[1]', 'integer'), 
        Effective_Date = prod.value('(Effective_Date/@value)[1]', 'datetime'), 
        Membership = prod.value('(Membership/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Request_ID = req.value('(Request_ID/@value)[1]', 'integer'),
        Request_type = req.value('(Request_type/@value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM myTable
    CROSS APPLY
        my_xml_column.nodes('/Root/Product') AS x1(prod)
    CROSS APPLY
        my_xml_column.nodes('/Root/Product/Request') AS x2(req)"
)

xml_df <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, xml_query)
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61b36e102ece703ba74b6d022f7c1408)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks :) Figured out where I was going wrong. Had to cast the XML column to XML and was able to use my own method in R to decompile it.

Comment: Indeed, as mentioned: *Below assumes XML column is stored as XML type.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps to seal this question, using code from the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71132129/3358272) answer.

Sample data:

```r
myframe <- structure(list(id = 1:2, xml = c("<Root>\n<Product>\n    <Test_ID value=\"1\" />\n    <Effective_Date value=\"2022-01-01\" />\n    <Membership value=\"Yes\" />\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"1\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Simple\" />\n    </Request>\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"2\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Complex\" />\n    </Request>\n</Product>\n</Root>", "<Root>\n<Product>\n    <Test_ID value=\"1\" />\n    <Effective_Date value=\"2022-01-01\" />\n    <Membership value=\"Yes\" />\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"3\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Simple\" />\n    </Request>\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"4\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Complex\" />\n    </Request>\n</Product>\n</Root>" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
myframe2 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, xml = c("<Root>\n<Product>\n    <Test_ID value=\"1\" />\n    <Effective_Date value=\"2022-01-01\" />\n    <Membership value=\"Yes\" />\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"1\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Simple\" />\n    </Request>\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"2\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Complex\" />\n    </Request>\n</Product>\n</Root>", "<Root>\n<Product>\n    <Test_ID value=\"1\" />\n    <Effective_Date value=\"2022-01-01\" />\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"3\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Simple\" />\n    </Request>\n    <Request>\n      <Request_ID value=\"4\" />\n      <Request_type value=\"Complex\" />\n    </Request>\n</Product>\n</Root>" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Functions from the previous answer:

```r
func1 <- function(z) if (is.null(names(z))) attr(z, "value") else lapply(z, func1)
merge.list <- function(A, B) {
  # normalize lengths, just in case, since I think you have more than one $Product
  A <- lapply(A, `length<-`, max(lengths(A)))
  B <- lapply(B, `length<-`, max(lengths(B)))
  BnotA <- setdiff(names(B), names(A))
  AnotB <- setdiff(names(A), names(B))
  inboth <- intersect(names(A), names(B))
  A[BnotA] <- replicate(length(BnotA), rep(NA, max(lengths(A))), simplify = FALSE)
  A[AnotB] <- lapply(A[AnotB], function(z) c(z, rep(NA, max(lengths(B)))))
  A[inboth] <- Map(c, A[inboth], B[inboth])
  A
}
```

Processing the column of xmls:

```r
intermediate <- lapply(myframe$xml, function(X) xml2::as_list(xml2::read_xml(X)))
final <- lapply(intermediate, function(L) {
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(func1(L$Root), function(pr) {
    as.data.frame(lapply(split(pr, names(pr)), function(Y) Reduce(merge.list, Y)))
  }))
})
final
# [[1]]
#           Effective_Date Membership Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
# Product.1     2022-01-01        Yes                  1               Simple       1
# Product.2     2022-01-01        Yes                  2              Complex       1
# [[2]]
#           Effective_Date Membership Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
# Product.1     2022-01-01        Yes                  3               Simple       1
# Product.2     2022-01-01        Yes                  4              Complex       1
```

Depending on the structures, you might be able to do:

```r
do.call(rbind, final)
#            Effective_Date Membership Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
# Product.1      2022-01-01        Yes                  1               Simple       1
# Product.2      2022-01-01        Yes                  2              Complex       1
# Product.11     2022-01-01        Yes                  3               Simple       1
# Product.21     2022-01-01        Yes                  4              Complex       1
```

If there are any differences (missing columns), then you might need one of the variants to `rbind` provided by other packages. For instance, if the second value of `myframe$xml` did not have `"Membership"` (as in `myframe2` above), then

```r
intermediate2 <- lapply(myframe2$xml, function(X) xml2::as_list(xml2::read_xml(X)))
final2 <- lapply(intermediate2, function(L) {
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(func1(L$Root), function(pr) {
    as.data.frame(lapply(split(pr, names(pr)), function(Y) Reduce(merge.list, Y)))
  }))
})
final2
# [[1]]
#           Effective_Date Membership Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
# Product.1     2022-01-01        Yes                  1               Simple       1
# Product.2     2022-01-01        Yes                  2              Complex       1
# [[2]]
#           Effective_Date Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
# Product.1     2022-01-01                  3               Simple       1
# Product.2     2022-01-01                  4              Complex       1
```

and unfortunately

```r
do.call(rbind, final2)
# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
#   numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

but we can do

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(final2)
#               Effective_Date Membership Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
# Product.1...1     2022-01-01        Yes                  1               Simple       1
# Product.2...2     2022-01-01        Yes                  2              Complex       1
# Product.1...3     2022-01-01       <NA>                  3               Simple       1
# Product.2...4     2022-01-01       <NA>                  4              Complex       1

data.table::rbindlist(final2, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
#    Effective_Date Membership Request.Request_ID Request.Request_type Test_ID
#            <char>     <char>             <char>               <char>  <char>
# 1:     2022-01-01        Yes                  1               Simple       1
# 2:     2022-01-01        Yes                  2              Complex       1
# 3:     2022-01-01       <NA>                  3               Simple       1
# 4:     2022-01-01       <NA>                  4              Complex       1
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans :) I'll give this a shot. Figured out what was going wrong on my end. Truly appreciate the help!